# How to enforce default text style for incoming mails?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, accessibility

One of my coworkers is handicapped with restricted vision and needs a very high contrast on his workspace. This works well for most applications, but it's not working for outlook-mails send as html/rich text, where a lot of other coworkers send colored mailtext, which is shown in grey in the high-contrast theme of Windows.

So I'd like to set his Outlook 2010 to either show text-only mails in the default (bigger) font or overwrite the default style in the mail with a custom setting to make his life easier. However, I did not find a way, if the mail already has a style applied by the sending user. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change all incoming mail to plain text and then set the plain text font size, etc..

1. Click the File menu > Options
2. On the left click Trust center > Trust center settings > E-mail security.
3. Enable both options: Read all standard mail in plain text and Read all digitally signed mail in plain text.
4. Click OK.
5. Click Tools > Mail Format > Stationery and Fonts.
6. Click on Fonts for Composing and reading plain text messages.
7. Select the required Font and click OK.